# How to link resouce bundle in framework to project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am development a framework and it's sample app. this framework contain some resource(images), I have make those resources to a bundle target. and I can copy bundle to sample app project, but Is it possible to link this bundle to sample app, then if bundle change, sample app side will get update otherwise have to copy bundle to it .

I add bundle to sample app in this way.
Build bundle as "Generic iOS device", then the red bundle file in products folder will turn entity. then drug it to "Build Phases"-> "Copy Bundle Resources", I choose "copy if need". if I don't select copy, it will link to ../Liberay/Developer/Xcode...